# How to get a menu to loop

Tags: c#

I am looking to get the menu to loop so when I enter the help menu and then return to the main menu it will actually run. Instead it doesn't respond when anything is entered. The exit also does not work for whatever reason and therefore I would appreciate any help given. Thank you.

```
    using System;

namespace MasterMind
{
    class Menu
    {
        public void DrawMainMenu()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("               MasterMind's Main Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("                    1: Play");
            Console.WriteLine("                    2: Help");
            Console.WriteLine("                    0: Exit");
        }
        public void DrawHelp()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Rules Of MasterMind!");
            Console.WriteLine("Mastermind is a game about guessing a 4 digit code. The numbers can range from");
            Console.WriteLine("1-4 and any other numbers will be rejected. It will say in the CMD");
            Console.WriteLine("prompt whether or not you had any of the number correct or false.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to go back to the main menu.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            DrawMainMenu();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void DrawExit()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You are about to exit the game");
            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure: Y/N");
            string userExit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
            if (userExit == "Y")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (userExit == "N")
            {
                DrawMainMenu();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var menu = new Menu();
            menu.DrawMainMenu();
            string userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
            if (userInput == "1")
            {

            }
            if (userInput == "2")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu.DrawHelp();
            }
            if (userInput == "0")
            {
                menu.DrawExit();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: voting to close this question as the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can get you started.

Note: there are improvements you can make to the structure and logic in various ways....I'll just give you one example e.g. having the `Environment.Exit(0);` where it is could be frowned upon...it could be avoided by having a "flag" on the while loop, which is set if you choose "exit", and then the program just exits naturally.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;

    namespace MasterMind
    {
        class Menu
        {
            public void DrawMainMenu()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("               MasterMind's Main Menu");
                Console.WriteLine("                    1: Play");
                Console.WriteLine("                    2: Help");
                Console.WriteLine("                    0: Exit");
            }
            public void DrawHelp()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Rules Of MasterMind!");
                Console.WriteLine("Mastermind is a game about guessing a 4 digit code. The numbers can range from");
                Console.WriteLine("1-4 and any other numbers will be rejected. It will say in the CMD");
                Console.WriteLine("prompt whether or not you had any of the number correct or false.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to go back to the main menu.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            public void DrawExit()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You are about to exit the game");
                Console.WriteLine("Are you sure: Y/N");
                string userExit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
                if (userExit.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var menu = new Menu();

                while (true)
                {
                    menu.DrawMainMenu();

                    string userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
                    if (userInput == "1")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Playing...");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    if (userInput == "2")
                    {
                        menu.DrawHelp();
                    }
                    if (userInput == "0")
                    {
                        menu.DrawExit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```